# How do I launch MS-DOS VM on Proxmox VE?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, dos, proxmox

How should I do ?
My hardware is N5105 mini PC.
And proxmox version: pve-manager/7.2-3/c743d6c1 (running kernel: 5.15.30-2-pve)

I want launch a MS-DOS VM on Proxmox VE.
And I have searched the Proxmox forum but did not find a similar solution.